# Buscar referencia a Swiper desde el DOM

Tags: jquery

Tengo varios swiper en mi pagina,

> http://idangero.us/swiper/api/

los cuales son creados dinámicamente.
Necesito  hacer un slideTo al hacer click en unos botones externo al swper.
Dichos banners tendran conoceran el objetoDOM que le corresponde al swiper-wrapper y un atributo para saber a que slide se lo debe enviar.

No encuentro la manera de obtener la instancia del objeto javascript swiper cosa de luego poder hacer un mySwiper.slideTo(indexSlide);

Answer (score 0):

En la página que compartes de Swiper dice ahí como obtener la referencia a dicho objeto:

```
var mySwiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container').swiper
```

En tu caso, sería cambiar el selector `.swiper-container` por uno que identifique especificamente al swiper generado dinámicamente del cual accionaron el botón externo. Si necesitas ayuda con eso comparte el HTML para ver como debe ser :)

---

> After you initialize Swiper it is possible to access to Swiper's
>   instance on its HTMLElement. It is swiper property of Swiper's HTML
>   container element:
>
> ```
> var mySwiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container').swiper
>
> // Now you can use all slider methods like
> mySwiper.slideNext();
> ```